# Tampermonkey script, make auto scroll with js

Tags: javascript, html, css, tampermonkey

I want to make a tampermonkey script but I have zero knowledge.
Purpose to read comic easier without scrolling.

I want to make tampermonkey with button on the page, location: right, down side.
When i click the button it will auto scroll from up to down.
And also if you can add speed variant like a volume of youtube: drag up(slower), drag down(faster).

I have an example of the auto scroll, links: https://codepen.io/michaelvinci/pen/qKVBLG?page=1&

Here's the button look like on the web:
[Button on web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhmzK.png)

here is code source From https://codepen.io/michaelvinci/pen/qKVBLG?page=1&:

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>
```

and script.js

```
let x = 0;
let startScroll;

$('.scrollable').scroll(function () {
  x = $(this).scrollTop();
})

$('#scroll-slider').on('input', function () {
  clearInterval(startScroll);
 
  
  if ($('#pause').hasClass('active')) {
    startScroll = setInterval(scroller, 400 / ($('#scroll-slider').val())); 
  }
});

$('.scroll-btn').on('click', function () {
  $('#play').toggleClass('active');
  $('#pause').toggleClass('active');
  
  if ($('#pause').hasClass('active')) {
    startScroll = setInterval(scroller, 800 /($('#scroll-slider').val()) ); 
  } else {
    clearInterval(startScroll);
  }
});

function scroller () {
  x += 1
  $('.scrollable').scrollTop(x); 
}
```

Comment: Were any of the below answers helpful to you? If so, please consider selecting one as the "best answer" (click the checkmark beside the answer), and upvoting any answers that were particularly well-written. It is allowable to upvote and checkmark the same answer. Doing so will acknowledge the answerers and close out the question, which is helpful to the StackOverflow community. You receive points each time you close out a question.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to change element `.scrollable` with `document`, for ui and speed just take it from codepen.

```
function scroller () {
  x += 1
  $(document).scrollTop(x); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also note that that is a jQuery script and we have a special way of including jQuery with our scripts.

Instead of the injecting the script tag `<script src=etcetera` that you posted, just add this bit to your userscript header:

```
// @require     https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
```

For example:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         americasvoice.news/shows
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @match        https://americasvoice.news/shows/
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

  // your script goes here

})();
```